# How can I distribute my iOS app to multiple countries?

Tags: ios, deployment

I'm currently working on my first iOS app (phonegap/cordova). I'm wondering if I need to take certain steps in order to make it available not only to the german app store (which is my language), but also international?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No you don't. **By default** it's distributed to all countries.

Comment: except if you select / deselect countries

Comment: maybe I should have put "by default" in bold.